# How "this" refers to DOM element in JQuery

Tags: jquery, this

```
function() {
 return this === window // true
}()
```

```
$("h1").click(function() {
 $(this).css({"color": "red"}) // "this" becomes DOM element(s) here.
})
```

How does `JQuery` implement `this` reference from `window` to `DOM element` for such a callback invocation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about scope! In general, the object bound to `this` in the current scope is determined by how the current function was called, it can't be set by assignment during execution, and it can be different each time the function is called.

EcmaScript 5 introduced the bind method to fix a function's `this` regardless of how it's called.

When the `this` keyword occurs inside a function, its value depends on how the function is called.

```
function() {
   return this === window // true, "this" would be the window
}

function f2(){
    "use strict"; 
    return this;  // "this" would return undefined in  strict mode
}

var o = {
  prop: 'test',
  f: function() {
    return this.prop; // here "this" would be the object o, and this.prop
                      // would equal o.prop
  }
};

var t = o.f(); // t is now 'test'
```

jQuery uses `call()` and `apply()` to change the value of `this` within a certain scope, and that is done like so:

```
function add(c, d){
  return this.a + this.b + c + d;
}

var o = {a:1, b:3};

// The first parameter is the object to use as 'this', 
//subsequent parameters are passed as 
// arguments in the function call
add.call(o, 5, 7); // 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 16

// The first parameter is the object to use as 'this', 
// the second is an array whose members are used 
//as the arguments in the function call
add.apply(o, [10, 20]); // 1 + 3 + 10 + 20 = 34
```

you can read a lot more about [**`this`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), [**`call()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [**`apply()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and other things on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) !

Answer (score 3):

It is done using the [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/event.js

```
thecallback.apply(theelement,theeventobject)
```

Here are the links to the code:

- https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/event.js#L262
- https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/event.js#L296
- https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/event.js#L301